# How are continuity of real and imaginary part related to continuity of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C},\ f=u+iv$ with $u,v\in\mathbb R$, which is is continuous with respect to the standard topology.

What is the weakest sufficient condition for the real and imaginary part of the function to be continuous as function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? When does the converse fail?

**Motivation**: I expected the condition on $f$ to be continuous is the same as the conditions of $u$ and $v$, but I come to ask this because the following sections on the Wikipedia article on [homolorphic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Definition): *A more satisfying converse, which is much harder to prove, is the Looman–Menchoff theorem: if f is continuous, u and v have first partial derivatives (but not necessarily continuous), and they satisfy the Cauchy–Riemann equations, then f is holomorphic.*

Why would they need to say $f$ is continuous if the real and imaginary part have derivatives, even?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $f$ is continuous if and only if the component functions are continuous (see [Continuity of a vector function through continuity of its components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307290/continuity-of-a-vector-function-through-continuity-of-its-components) for example).

Notice that your original function is $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ but in the wikipedia article they are talking about functions from $\mathbb C$ to itself.  So these may be viewed as functions $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.  In dimensions two and higher, saying that the partial derivatives exist does not imply that the function is continuous (e.g. Pedro's answer).

Comment: yea good point.

Comment: Okay thanks. In the definition of the complex derivative, do we not require the function to be continuous?

Comment: @NickKidman If a function is complex differentiable, it is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&x \text{ or } y\neq 0\\0& x=y=0\end{cases}$$ has partial derivatives, but is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @EricO.Korman No, it is not...

Comment: ok looks good now :-)

Comment: @EricO.Korman Nothing changed, really. ;)