# Showing that stereographic projection is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, conformal-geometry, stereographic-projections

For any $n\geq 0$, the ***unit $n$-sphere*** is the space $S^{n}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$
defined by
$$
S^{n}=S^{n}(1) := 
\left\{ (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n+1})
\;\middle\vert\; 
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}^{2} = 1 \right\}
$$
with the subspace topology. The point $P = (0, \dots, 0, 1)$ in $S^{n}$ called the ***north pole.***
Then we have the following conclusion:

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad$ For any $n\geq 0$, $S^{n}$ with the north pole removed is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

---

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image: FIGURE 1-1]

From **FIGURE 1-1** ,we define a map
$$
f: S^{n} \setminus \{P\} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}, 
\quad x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}} \cdot (x_1, \cdots , x_n).
$$

(This map is called ***stereographic projection***.)

It can be described geometrically as follows: Given a point
$x = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n+1}) \in S^{n} \setminus \{P\}$, stereographic projection sets $f(x) = y$, where $(y, 0)$ is the point where the line through $P$ and $x$ meets the subspace $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \{0\}$ at $u = (y,0) = (y_{1}, \dots, y_{n}, y_{n+1})$.

Hence,
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
u = \lambda x+(1-\lambda )P \\ 
y_{n+1} = 0
\end{matrix}\right. 
\quad(\lambda \in\mathbb{R}) \Longrightarrow 
\lambda = \frac{1}{1-{x}_{n+1}}.
$$
So the analytical expression of the ***stereographic projection*** is
$$
f(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n+1}) 
= \left( \frac{x_{1}}{1-{x}_{n+1}}, \dots, \frac{x_{n}}{1-{x}_{n+1}} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$

---

From the geometric intuition,we can get the map $f: S^{n} \setminus \{P\} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bijective, but how can I prove it  theoretically. Further, I need some rigorous proofs that $f: S^{n} \setminus \{P\} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a homeomorphism. **(We must strictly demonstrate that $f$ is injective, surjective, and continuous.)**

Another question:

I know the analytical expression of the inverse $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to S^{n} \setminus \{P\}$  is
$$
f^{-1} (y_1, \dots, y_n) 
= \frac{1}{\|y\|^2 + 1}(2y_1, \dots, 2y_n, \|y\|^2 - 1), 
\quad \text{where } \|y\|^2 = y_1^2 + \dots + y_n^2.
$$
But how can I get this expression?

Who can provide some related materials or solutions about these? (**I want use some knowledge of *Differential Calculus in Several Variables* to solve these questions**). Any of your help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think using topological language will be useful and give a cleaner proof than epsilon-delta language in showing the continuity. By considering the composition of f and the projection maps, we can show the continuity clearly. After all, when we are talking about homeomorphisms, we are dealing with topological properties.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2175456/721644).

Answer (score 11):

Hint: To show that $f$ is bijective, one can often (as can be managed here) compute $f^{-1}$ explicitly. Then, to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, by definition it remains to show that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, but they are both visibly compositions of continuous functions.

Comment: Is $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ a compact space? I think it isn't because $S^n$ is closed and removing a point from it no longer makes it a closed space.

Comment: It is noncompact for $n > 0$ (but notice that for $n = 0$ it is compact, so the reasoning you give cannot hold in general).

Comment: Right, for $n=0$ , it is just $x^2 = 1$ that is two points +1, -1. I don't want to say $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ is not compact as is it is homeomorphic to $R^n$ which is non-compact. I think going back to the basic definition of compactness, around $\{p\} = (0,0,...1)$ open cover generated by open balls on $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ with fixed n-th co-ordinate $x_n = (1- \dfrac{1}{n}) \ \ \forall n$ have no finite subcover, hence it is non-compact. Please tell me if I make sense.

Comment: That's correct, but I'm not sure why you're concerned with compactness in this situation.

Comment: Nothing particularly, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, stereographic projection maps circles to circles, and so for topological reasons $f$ maps open disks in the planes into open discs on $S^n - \{p\}$ (regions with circular boundary). But the set of open disks in the plane is a basis for the standard topology on the plane, and hence (once you know it exists) $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Similarly, so is $f$.

Comment: I want use some knowledge of Differential Calculus in Several Variables to solve these questions.eg:the implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})$ be the point in the sphere whose projection on the plane is $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$. As you said before, the relation between the coordinates of those points is:
\begin{equation} y_i = \frac{x_i}{1-x_{n+1}} \quad \forall i \in \{ 1,\ldots, n \}, \end{equation}
with $y_{n+1} = 0$. We want to find the inverse of the projection, $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^n-\{p\}$, i.e. we want to find $x_i$ as a function of $y_i$, given $y_i$. But the above relation only gives us $n$ equations and we have $n+1$ unknowns. To find one more equation, we can do some reverse-engineering. For $f^{-1}$ to be well defined, it is necessary that the output be a point of the sphere. This gives us the extra equation we needed:
$$ x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 = 1.$$
Plugging in the above relations:
$$ 1 = (1-x_{n+1})^2(y_1^2+\ldots + y_n^2) + x_{n+1}^2 = (1-x_{n+1})^2||y||^2 + x_{n+1}^2.$$
Equivalently, this is a second order equation with $x_{n+1}$ being the only unknown:
$$ (1-||y||^2)x_{n+1}^2 -2||y||^2x_{n+1} + (||y||^2-1) = 0.$$
If you apply the classical formula to solve this equation, you either get $x_{n+1} = 1$ or $x_{n+1} = 1 - 2/(1+||y||^2)$. Since we know that $x_{n+1}$ must satisfy the initial relations, it is obvious that the first solution must be discarded, so $x_{n+1} = 1 - 2/(1+||y||^2)$. Plugging this in the initial equations, we get:
$$ x_i = \frac{2y_i}{1+||y||^2} \quad \forall i \in \{ 1,\ldots, n \},$$
$$ x_{n+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{1+||y||^2} = \frac{||y||^2-1}{1+||y||^2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions in your post: **i)** How to prove that $f\circ f^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ f = \text{Id}$ and bicontinuity, **ii)** how to obtain the expression for the inverse?

**ii)** I myself tried to do this geometrically, but at least I haven't managed to do so. My best guess would be: Take $n = 2$ or $n = 3$, do it analytically there and then generalize to an arbitrary number of dimensions. Once you have it, you can explicitly show **i)**. Or maybe one can even take the general definition of the stereographic projection and invert it in general...

**i)** Concerning the bicontinuity, I refer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307290/continuity-of-a-vector-function-through-continuity-of-its-components) and the already given answers.

- Let's first prove that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$, where $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$. This one is straightforward: $$ f(f^{-1}(x)) = f\left( \left( \frac{2x_1}{1+||x||_2^2}, \dots, \frac{2x_n}{1+||x||_2^2}, 1-\frac{2}{1+||x||_2^2} \right)^T \right) = \dots = x.$$
  Again, this one is straightforward, just use the stereographic map $f$.
- Now let's prove that $f^{-1}(f(x))$, where $x\in S^n\backslash\{p\}\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$: $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}} \begin{pmatrix}x_1, \dots, x_n\end{pmatrix}^T \right)$$

I will prove $f^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}\begin{pmatrix}x_1, \dots, x_n\end{pmatrix}^T\right) = x$ by proving $f^{-1}(\dots)_i = x_i$, where I denote by $f^{-1}(\dots)_i$ the $i$-th component of $f^{-1}(\dots)$ for $i\in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, and by separately proving $f^{-1}(\dots)_n = x_n$. I do this because of the way that $f^{-1}$ is given: The last component of the input is transformed differently than the other components.

So, let's start with $f^{-1}(f(x))_i$: $$f^{-1}(f(x))_i = \frac{2x_i}{1-x_{n+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\lvert\lvert \frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}\begin{pmatrix}x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}^T \rvert\rvert_2^2} = \frac{2x_i}{1-x_{n+1}+\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2}.$$
We can now use two facts: Firstly, $\lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert_2^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2 + x_{n+1}^2$, since $x\in S^n\backslash \{p\}\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$. Secondly, $\lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert_2^2 = 1$, by definition of the unit ball. Thus, we can rewrite $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2 = 1-x_{n+1}^2$: $$ f^{-1}(f(x))_i = \frac{2x_i}{1-x_{n+1}+\frac{1-x_{n+1}^2}{1-x_{n+1}}} = \dots = x_i,$$ which is now easy to show. Similarly, we can show that $f^{-1}(f(x))_n = x_n$. $\blacksquare$