# $S^1-\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$S^1-\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, drawing the picture I understand but I find difficulty in finding map. Please help . Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that stereographic projection is a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122931/showing-that-stereographic-projection-is-a-homeomorphism)

Answer (score 3):

Just consider the homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto $S^1\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ define by$$x\mapsto\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2},\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You can write the required homomorphism as the composition of two functions:
$$t\longmapsto(\cos t,\sin t),\qquad t\in(-\pi,\pi)$$
and
$$x\longmapsto 2\arctan x,\qquad x\in\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

This homeomorphism can be seen as the $v={}$central projection from $P$ onto the $x$-axis:
[image]
Now the equation of line $(PH)$ is $\;\dfrac x1+\dfrac y{x_H}=1$. As it passes through $M(\cos t,\sin t)$, we have
$$\cos t+\frac{\sin t}{x_H}=1,\quad\text{whence }\quad x_H=\frac{\sin t}{1-\cos t}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ell$ be a line parallel to the tangent line to $S^1$ at $p.$ A line through $p$ other than the tangent line intersects $S^1$ once and intersects $\ell$ once. That's a homeomorphism.