# When are functions continuous on a product metric space?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

There are a few natural ways to construct a product metric space from pre-existing ones [(article)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393111/continuity-of-a-function-of-product-spaces) but what condition do we need on spaces/ functions for it to be that the continuity of component function (w.r.t metric components) imply continuity of whole function on the product space?

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256906/does-factor-wise-continuity-imply-continuity?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems to answer it is not easy but this [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307498/688539) does it for the 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$ . I feel the result in the second mentioned post could be at least generalized for different metrics on $\mathbb{R}^d$, could it? What would be the generalized result?